# Why does Xamarin profiler continuously opening mlpd file?

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

when I launch Xamarin Profiler its continuously shows Wait progress.

- option Enable Developer Instrument is checked
- All .mlpd files is empty

Each Profilers log containts next info:

`XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:41.1374] ##########################################
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:41.1394] # Xamarin Profiler version -  1.6.1.483
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:41.1404] #  * Arch x86_64
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:41.1404] ##########################################
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:41.3025] initializing android platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:41.3025] initializing ios platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:41.3025] initializing mlpd platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:41.4258] processing command line = C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin\Profiler\XamarinProfiler.exe --type=android --target=SiversPocket.SiversPocket|md58dfdb85a684bd0751892280cc69d3885.MainActivity --device=a2dba988 --options=name:Xiaomi Redmi 3
XamarinProfiler.Windows.Core.WindowsRunFactory Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:56.7017] Creating android run for SiversPocket.SiversPocket|md58dfdb85a684bd0751892280cc69d3885.MainActivity target on device a2dba988
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:56.7237] Start profiling...
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:56.7646] Waiting for device connection a2dba988
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:56.7676] StartRecording for SiversPocket.SiversPocket
XamarinProfiler.Core.Platforms.Android.ProfileAndroidRun Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:58.0043] checking runtime version on device Xiaomi Redmi 3
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:44:58.7136] Running application SiversPocket.SiversPocket.md58dfdb85a684bd0751892280cc69d3885.MainActivity
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:45:00.7055] Running Android Profiler on Xiaomi  Redmi 3 device with heapshot=ondemand,alloc,nocalls,maxframes=8,counters,
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2018-10-31 11:45:01.1788] Opening C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\Temp\crefolma.mlpd`

Comment: Is there other recent changes about Xamarin,or every project is like this?You can offer more info about it.

Comment: i have changed device and now profiler working fine

Comment: Haha,you are terrific!